# What are strategies for maximizing functions--specifically for finding the MLE--without using the derivative (statistics)?

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

I know how to use the MLE, just I run into trouble when I can't maximize the likelihood function with its derivative.

As an example, I know that the MLE for a uniform distribution with parameter $B$ is $\hat{B}=\max(X)$ where $X$ is the observed data. I do not understand why though.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

The process of learning calculus has a tendency to ingrain the notion of the calculation of global extrema as an exercise in differentiation of continuous functions with infinite support, to locate critical points.  However, this is only a special case of a much broader class of optimization problems, and the methods that one can use do not always involve such a narrow approach.

If I gave you the following function:  $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & 0 < x \le 1/2 \\ 2, & 1/2 < x \le 3/4, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$ what would you say was the maximum value attainable for $f$?  Would you set about answering such a question by taking the derivative, looking for critical points?  Of course not; that is absurd.

In a similar vein, would you verify that $f$ is a legitimate density function by integrating $f$?  Or would you simply calculate $1(1/2 - 0) + 2(3/4 - 1/2) = 1$?

The tools of calculus are powerful but they are not always the tools of first resort.  You have to first **think** about what it is you are trying to achieve, and choose the most appropriate mathematical method to achieve it.  If you reflexively think "differentiation -> critical points -> extrema," you have effectively neglected this initial step.

Here is another example.  Suppose a random variable $X$ has the following distribution:  $$\Pr[X = 0] = \theta/6, \quad \Pr[X = 1] = \theta/3, \quad \Pr[X = 2] = 1 - \theta/2.$$  You can verify that for any $\theta \in [0,2]$, the above distribution is a legitimate probability mass function.

Now what if I said, "given a **single** observation from this distribution, what is the MLE of $\theta$?"  How would you go about answering such a question?

Well, let's construct the likelihood given a single observation.  $$\mathcal L(\theta \mid x) = f(x \mid \theta) = \ldots?$$  Wait, this is weird.  What do you write?  Well, the probability mass function is $$\Pr[X = x] = \begin{cases} \theta/6, & x = 0 \\ \theta/3, & x = 1 \\ 1 - \theta/2, & x = 2. \end{cases}$$  It's *piecewise*.  So, the likelihood is also piecewise.  What this tells you is that $\mathcal L$ is three different functions of $\theta$, depending on the observed outcome $x$.  Now the key is to ask, "for each of the three outcomes, what allowable value of $\theta$ can you choose that makes $\mathcal L$ as big as possible?"

For example, suppose we observed $x = 0$.  Then $\mathcal L(\theta \mid x = 0) = \theta/6$.  You might say, "but I can make this value as big as I want!"  Indeed, if you differentiate it with respect to $\theta$, you will find no critical points.  But remember, $\theta$ cannot exceed $2$:  the reason is that $\Pr[X = 2] = 1 - \theta/2$, and this value, being a probability, cannot be less than $0$.  So, in the case where we observed $x = 0$, the maximum likelihood estimate is $\hat \theta = 2$.

If you do the same for the other cases, you will find that for a single observation $x$, $$\hat \theta = \begin{cases} 2, & x \in \{0, 1\} \\ 0, & x = 2. \end{cases}$$  There are no other possibilities.

Note we didn't use calculus at all.  We just used basic mathematical reasoning, founded upon a precise understanding of the question at hand.

When it comes to the MLE for a parameter $\theta$ where $U \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,\theta)$, the idea is the same:  for an IID sample $\boldsymbol u = (u_1, \ldots, u_n)$, we construct the joint density $$f(\boldsymbol u \mid \theta) = \begin{cases} \theta^{-n}, & u_1, \ldots, u_n \in [0, \theta] \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  We can do better, though, because we note that in the sample $(u_1, \ldots, u_n)$, there must be a smallest element and a largest element, which we will call $u_{(1)}$ and $u_{(n)}$, respectively.  Then we can write $$\mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol u) = f(\boldsymbol u \mid \theta) = \begin{cases} \theta^{-n}, & 0 \le u_{(1)} \le u_{(n)} \le \theta, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  And now what?  We see that if we regard the sample as being fixed, and $\theta$ the unknown variable in the likelihood, then the likelihood is largest when $\theta$ is as small as permissible.  But since the sample is fixed, $\theta$ cannot be smaller than $u_{(n)}$, else the "otherwise" case "kicks in" and the likelihood is zero.  But if $\theta$ is larger than $u_{(n)}$, then we are suboptimal, because we're allowing $\theta$ larger than it needs to be, making $\mathcal L$ smaller than it needs to be.  Therefore, $$\hat \theta = u_{(n)} = \max(u_1, \ldots, u_n),$$ the maximum observation in the sample.

Comment: In the above answer, as the $f(u\mid\Theta) = \theta^{-n}$, shouldn't the $\theta$ be $\min(u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n)$? to maximize the likelihood?